# Remove "add new product category" link

Tags: css, wordpress

I need "add new product category" link from the metabox removed in the backend of my wordpress site.
How can I remove this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this - add this code to 
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/admin.css

```
#product_cat-add-toggle{ 
    display:none;
}
```

or create a plugin that applies style

Comment: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/admin.css                                       Where is this located, please?

Comment: I'm still learning a lot when it comes to coding so I am completely unsure of how to add code to "wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/admin.css" as I have no idea where this is located. Help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I figured out where the code needs to go.                                                             BUT, THANK YOU SO MUCH for code as it worked!

Comment: "wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/admin.css" is a path to the file on your hosting or wherever the place where your wordpress files are keep. You could add this three lines of code to the end of the admin.css file. I'm glad I could help.